# button in fragment not working when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a button in fragment, and for that button i had override onClick() method, but its not working.
i have a Taost and a Log too when the button is being clicked.

```
public class DataShown extends Fragment  implements OnClickListener{

Button tv;
TextView textview;
Activity activity=getActivity();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("3", "started");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datashown, container, false);
    Log.d("3", "closed");
    textview=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.configButton);
    tv.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) activity);
return rootView;
}//onCtreate

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("onClick","1");
    Toast.makeText(activity, "on click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

why its happening, i have no idea, may be its silly mistake.
Now the toast is showing error, is accepts context object so i provided activity, not working.

Comment: use   `tv.setOnClickListener(this);`. Fragment implements `OnClickListener`. also use `getActivity()` after fragment is attached to the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
tv.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) activity);
```

to

```
tv.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and in `onClick` method  change

```
Toast.makeText(activity, "on click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "on click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and remove

```
Activity activity=getActivity();
```

because you did initiate it before fragment attached to activity.

Comment: why its not working when it have written Activity activity=getActivity();

Comment: @RaghavendraShivhare because `activity` is null in your case,either use as I suggested or initialize `activity` in `onCreateView` method.

Comment: @RaghavendraShivhare Happy to help,enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the view in the fragment, but binding the on click listener to the activity.
`tv.setOnClickListener(this);` since fragment is the one tat is overriding the onClick listener and not the activity

Comment: fragment class is implementing the interface `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Yon can do this:
    tv.setOnClickListener(getActivity);

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with your context in `setOnClickListener`, you need to give your actvivities context to work fine.

`setOnClickListener(getActivity);` will pass the actvities context to the onclicklistner.