# Android - Call Method With A Button From XML

Tags: android, sql, xml, button, onclick

I've got an app based on `Sliding Tabs` layout. I want to call the `addMedicine` method in the `PageFragment` class from an XML layout with a `Button`. The issue is that i cannot assign the method to the `Button` `onClick` event.

Here's the `PageFragment` class:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

// TEMP VARIABLES //
ListView ItemsLst;
String[] Items = {"Medicine 1", "Medicine 2", "Medicine 3"};
TextView output;

EditText nameFld;
EditText formatFld;
EditText amountFld;
EditText exp_dateFld;
EditText timeFld;

DBManager dbAdapt = new DBManager(getActivity());

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = null;
    switch(mPage)
    {
        case 1:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_sqltest, container, false);

            nameFld = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameFld);
            formatFld = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.formatFld);
            amountFld = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.amountFld);
            exp_dateFld = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exp_dateFld);
            timeFld = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.timeFld);

            return view;
        case 2:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_settings, container, false);
            return view;
        case 3:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_info, container, false);
            return view;
    }
    return view;
}

public void addMedicine() // The method i want to call
{
    String name = nameFld.getText().toString();
    String format = formatFld.getText().toString();
    int amount = Integer.parseInt(amountFld.getText().toString());
    String exp_date = exp_dateFld.getText().toString();
    String time = timeFld.getText().toString();

    long id = dbAdapt.addMedicine(name, format, amount, exp_date, time);

}
}
```

And here is the `layout_sqltest` XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/nameLbl"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nameFld"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Format"
        android:id="@+id/formatLbl"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/formatFld"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:id="@+id/amountLbl"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/amountFld"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Expiration Date"
        android:id="@+id/exp_dateLbl"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/exp_dateFld"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Time"
        android:id="@+id/timeLbl"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timeFld"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Medicine"
        android:id="@+id/addMedicineBtn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `addMedicineBtn` is the button i want to call the method with.
Someone can help me? I really need that!
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I tried giving to `addMedicine` method the `View` param, but it still doesn't appear in the available methods for the `addMedicineBtn` in the `onClick` properties (I'm using Android Studio).

Comment: The question has been closed as duplicate, so I can't write an answer. Unfortunately for you the answers to the linked questions won't help you either, because it's not the same question. The onClick() in a layout xml can only call a callback in an activity, to do the same in a fragment, you have to programmatically assign a `View.OnClickListener()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Comment: @ci_ you can answer now. I messed up, it happens. If you disagree with a closing you can always ping the closer to discuss your opinion on it. I just happened to revisit this

Comment: @codeMagic Don't worry, as you said, it can happen. Anyway, i tried using the OnClickListener but the `addMedicine()` method still doens't appear in the onClick properties of the `Button`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: As @ci_ said "to do the same in a fragment, you have to programmatically assign a View.OnClickListener()" you can't set it in xml for a fragment. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968198/button-in-fragment-not-working-when-clicked) for example

Comment: @codeMagic I'm sorry but i'm a newbie with this, so if you can post an answer with the code it would be very useful, because i didn't find any example on the web. Thank you and sorry for troubles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use onClickListener

`view.findViewById(R.id.addMedicineBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addMedicine();
        }
});`

Comment: Ok that's what i was looking for. I just assigned the Listener with the wrong method. Thank you all folks!

Answer (score 0):

You must add `tools:context="PageFragment"` line to the container (`LinearLayout`) of `PagerFragment`'s layout file (`layout_sqltest`). Then `onClick()` method will find methods in `PagerFragment` class.